# Separate column from array using php

Tags: php, pivot

I am trying to plot bar graph using chart.js and from mssql database.I am able to retrieve data from the database in array.I have used following code,

```
<?php    
$serverName = "PC";   
$uid = "sa";     
$pwd = "PC#1234";    
$databaseName = "climate";   
$dsn = "sql"; 

$conn= odbc_connect ($dsn ,$uid ,$pwd);
if(!$conn){
    echo('Connection Failed');
}
$sql="select convert(nvarchar(100), DVCDTxp_Datetime,106)   )";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs){
    exit("Error in SQL");
}

echo odbc_result_all($rs);

$response = array();
for($i=1;$i<= odbc_num_rows($rs);$i++){
    $row = odbc_fetch_array($rs,$);
    $response[] = $row;
}
?>
```

I am getting following output,

```
DATE            AVG_VAL
06 Jun 2015     5.466593   
08 Jun 2015     1.774121 
09 Jun 2015     .729223
11 Jun 2015     3.329457 
12 Jun 2015     2.344660
```

I want the following output ,

```
DATE=["06 Jun 2015","08 Jun 2015","09 Jun 2015","11 Jun 2015","12 Jun 2015"]
VALUE=["5.466593","1.774121",".729223","3.329457","2.344660"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating array `$response` so assuming array keys to be indexed and starting from zero.

If not, use `array_values()` inside `json_encode()` while echoing.

```
$all_dates = array_map(function($val){ return $val['DATE']; }, $response);

$all_values = array_map(function($val){ return (float)$val['AVG_VAL']; }, $response);
```

Use as,

```
DATE = <?php echo json_encode($all_dates)?>

VALUE = <?php echo json_encode($all_values)?>
```

Comment: I haven' t tested it, but in the second array map you have an issue. You are converting the value to integer, which is wrong. You either have to use float or leave the type untouched (if you don't want the leading zero in the output).

Comment: yes, my mistake, it needs to be `(float)`, i'll just edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to odbc_fetch_array but i think there should $i instead of just $

Also if you can fetch record you can use array_push() in storing those in array as

```
$date=array();
$value=array();
```

in your for loop

```
array_push($date,$row['date']);
array_push($value,$row['avg_value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `$response` is in this shape, perhaps [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can help:

```
$response = array(
    array("DATE" => "06 Jun 2015", "AVG_VAL" => 5.466593),
    array("DATE" => "08 Jun 2015", "AVG_VAL" => 1.774121),
    array("DATE" => "09 Jun 2015", "AVG_VAL" => 0.729223),
    array("DATE" => "11 Jun 2015", "AVG_VAL" => 3.329457),
    array("DATE" => "12 Jun 2015", "AVG_VAL" => 2.344660)
);

$date = array_column($response, 'DATE');
$value = array_column($response, 'AVG_VAL');
```